# times table generator python - syntax error

Tags: syntax-error, python-3.4

the error is on line 10. no clue why it crashes. the equals sign is highlighted red once it is run.
code as follows:

```
import random

question = 1
correct = 0

while question < 10:
    a = random.randint(1, 12)
    b = random.randint(1, 12)
    answer = input(a, 'x', b, '=')
    if 'answer' = 'a*b':
        print ('correct!')
        correct = correct+1
    else:
        print ('Incorrect\nthe correct answer was', a*b)

print ('You got', correct, 'out of 10 correct')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your if statement to this:

```
if answer == a*b:
```

Using `=` assigns the value where `==` tests equality.

The other issue is that you have too many arguments for the input function. Input takes one argument, that is a string to output to the command line to show the user. Then the input comes in as a string and you cannot directly compare string's to integers so you need to convert the string to an integer.

```
answer = input("Enter in the answer for {} * {}".format(a,b))
answer = int(answer)
```

Comment: Thanks for the Help, Kind of obvious though. didn't notice at first